# Excel filter check boxes not matching excel filter 'Number Filter'

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column with positive, negative and zero values. I want to filter the column to return only values greater than 0. When I go through the drop down check box list that includes all unique values and uncheck all of the negative (and the one 0) values, the number of records that are returned is ~127,000. When I navigate to Number Filter > Greater Than and use a number filter that returns all records > 0, I get ~230,000 records.

What am I doing wrong here? Are there any traps in using the number filter with check boxes that I'm falling in to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try creating and testing a small representative sample of your data and [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1680439/edit) to include the sample and the results you get.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question (any traps in using the number filter vs check boxes), they work as good as your data.

I'm guessing that you have the numbers reversed in your description. That is, I think you get 127k when using the number filter > 0, and you have 230k when deselecting your negative and 0 boxes.

Then in your data, you have either blank values (which you didn't uncheck), or numbers-formatted-as-text values. That would explain the difference, as the > filter would not include the blank or text-formatted values.